# Clearance while creating a sandbox user in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

To create a user in a Sandbox I need my username, password, and security token.
I also need to point to test.salesforce.com, instead of login.salesforce.com.

However, I am not clear on the privileges required for creating a user through the APIs.

If I can create a user in the Sandbox through the Setup/Admin/Users/Create New, should I also be able to create a user through the APIs?

Do I need to be an admin of the Prod account to be able to create user through the API in the Sandbox, or is it enough for me to be a sys admin in the sandbox?

I ask that because I am trying to create a user in a sandbox and I am getting a

```
Caused by: [LoginFault [ApiFault  exceptionCode='INVALID_LOGIN'
exceptionMessage='Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.'
```

I know the user is not locked out, and I know the other credentials are correct, so that makes me think this is about rights.

Answer (score 0):

If you have permissions to create a user, you can do this by using enterprise api.

It is working for me.

```
User u = new User();
u.setUsername(Username);
u.setFirstName(FirstName);
u.setLastName(LastName);
u.setEmail(Email);
SaveResult[] results = connection.create(new SObject[] { u });
```

Regards,

Naveen

[autorabit](http://www.autorabit.com)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by creating a Sandbox in a different account. Instead of creating a Sandbox of our production account, we created a different partner account, which didn't have SSO enabled. That solved the issue. We don't know what settings would require an SSO to be able to use the APIs, but the SSO was in the way of calling the APIs.